# Quartz Java Scheduler Example with Job Class taking command line input

Tags: java, triggers, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am having hard time finding a perfect working example for a Simple Java Quartz example.

Consider a class Sum which takes **2 arguments from the command line** always 1 and 2 and prints the result as 3.

I need to schedule this class running everyday midnight 00.00hrs passing the arguments.

Can anyone give me a headstart(code snippet)!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples work pretty well. Try downloading from this link.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads

Example 1 works like a charm.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example1

It has a shell script you can execute on both windows and linux OS.

EDIT: If you want to dynamically change scheduling of jobs based on user input, then [this](http://devside.blogspot.in/2010/08/dynamic-rescheduling-by-spring-quartz.html) example may be better for you. It requires you to know spring though.

Comment: Thanks for the links! ..Can you be more precise on how do I pass data from Scheduler to the Job as in I have a java application which takes command line input, so how do I send the input from the scheduler to the application.

Comment: Look at this tutorial for example. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.

Comment: Updated the answer with a new suggestion. Check it out and see if that works for you.